# Show by mathematical induction that $(2n)! > 2^n*n!$ for all $n \geq 2$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Very stuck on this question. Here is what I have attempted.

Base case: $(2*2)! > 2^2*2!$ = $24>8$ Which is true

Hypothesis: Assume for some int k>2 that $(2k)!>2^k*k!$

Then for my inductive step, I am getting stuck. I tried,

$(2(k+1))! > 2^{k+1} *(k+1)!$

$(2k+2)!> 2^{k+1} *(k+1)! $

$(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)!>2* 2^{k} *(k+1)! $

And then I'm stuck... I understand I am supposed to use my IH somewhere, but I do not understand how to effectively apply it in this step. Can somebody clearly show me how I should use the IH?

Comment: Induction?  Much easier to just note that $(2n)!=\overbrace {1\times \cdots \times n}^{\text {= n!}}\times \overbrace {(n+1)\times \cdots \times (2n)}^{\text {n terms}}$

Comment: I must use induction here.

Comment: Seems contrived.  But fine, split off the $n!$ as before and apply induction to show that the second factor $>2^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(2(k+1))! \overset{?}{>} 2^{k+1}(k+1)!$$

$$(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)! \overset{?}{>} \cdot2^{k+1}(k+1)!$$

$$(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)! \overset{?}{>} 2 \cdot2^k(k+1)k!$$

Now use your IH, since $(2k)! > 2\cdot2^k k!$, you just need to show that

$$(2k+2)(2k+1) > (k+1),$$

which is obvious.

Comment: I think you may have written one too many 2s

Comment: You are right, my bad, I was rewriting your 3rd line which said $(2k)!>2^k∗2k!$ with an extra 2, instead of looking at the title.

Comment: So it's really my bad, edited for clarity

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there:
$$
\begin{align}
(2(k+1))! &= (2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)! \\
&> (2k+2)(2k+1) 2^k k! \quad \text{(by the induction hypothesis)}\\
&= 2(k+1)(2k+1) 2^k k! \\
&= (2k+1) 2^{k+1} (k+1)! \\
&> 2^{k+1} (k+1)!
\end{align}
$$

Without induction:
$$
(2n)! = (1 \cdot 2 \cdots n) \cdot ((n+1) \cdots (2n)) > n! \cdot (2 \cdots 2) = 2^n \, n!
$$

Comment: Isn't induction 'undercover' anyway, when extending $a < b \Rightarrow ca < cb$ for $c >0$ to arbitrary (finite) products?

Comment: @GuidoA., sure.

Comment: This style of inductive step confuses me. Where does the right hand side of the inequality come from?

Comment: @SolidSnackDrive, it's the induction hypothesis: $(2k)!>2^k k!$.

Answer (score 0):

We need to show $$(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)!>2* 2^{k} *(k+1)!$$

We know that $$(2k)!>2^k*k!$$

Thus $$(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)!> (2k+2)(2k+1)2^k*k!>2^{k+1}*(k+1)!  $$

Answer (score 0):

Using induction, you get

$$(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)! = 2(k+1)(2k+1)(2k)! >$$

$$ > 2 \cdot 2^k \cdot (k+1)(k)!$$

Dividing both sides by $2(k+1)$ you are left with

$$(2k+1)(2k)! > 2^k(k)!$$

Using that $2k+1 \geq 1$ it the follows from your induction hypothesis.

Comment: Damn, I knew there was no way I could get in first writing on this tablet haha